# Enable Guest Account via Profile Manager

Tags: macos, profile-manager, guest-account

I am the sole IT guy in a small school that is all Mac. I have about 40 student MacBooks to manage and about 40 student iMacs as well. I would like to manage them as best I can using Profile Manager. One thing I need to do is enable the Guest Account on the student computers.  Can this be done via Profile Manager, or is this yet another thing that will cause me to go around logging onto and configuring all the student computers?

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute a configuration profile to enable it, courtesy of [@gregneagle on GitHub](https://github.com/gregneagle/profiles/blob/master/loginwindow.mobileconfig). The following is a stripped down version to just the payload for setting the guest account on.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
>     <key>PayloadContent</key>
>     <array>
>         <dict>
>             <key>DisableGuestAccount</key>
>             <true/>
>             <key>EnableGuestAccount</key>
>             <false/>
>             <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
>             <string>Login Window:  MCX Preferences</string>
>             <key>PayloadEnabled</key>
>             <true/>
>             <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
>             <string>com.github.gregneagle.loginwindow.MCX</string>
>             <key>PayloadType</key>
>             <string>com.apple.MCX</string>
>             <key>PayloadUUID</key>
>             <string>497c36d1-422c-b5e0-c23e-b1138b2d490a</string>
>             <key>PayloadVersion</key>
>             <integer>1</integer>
>             <key>SleepDisabled</key>
>             <false/>
>         </dict>
>     </array>
>     <key>PayloadDescription</key>
>     <string>Loginwindow configuration settings</string>
>     <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
>     <string>Loginwindow Configuration</string>
>     <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
>     <string>com.github.gregneagle.loginwindow</string>
>     <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
>     <string></string>
>     <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
>     <true/>
>     <key>PayloadScope</key>
>     <string>System</string>
>     <key>PayloadType</key>
>     <string>Configuration</string>
>     <key>PayloadUUID</key>
>     <string>0dc319a0-c331-0131-eeb5-000c294ab81b</string>
>     <key>PayloadVersion</key>
>     <integer>1</integer>
> </dict>
> </plist>
> ```

Comment: How do I bundle this up and distribute it to devices?